# JPA testing UniqueConstraint

Tags: testing, jpa, playframework, constraints

I would like to test UniqueConstraint in JPA/Playframework:

```
    @Test
    public void saveWithTitleNotUnique() {  // not unique title

        Software software1 = builder.template1().withTitle("title1").create();
        Software software2 = builder.template1().withTitle("title1").create();

        software1.save();

        try {
            software2.save();
            fail("software.title is not unique");
        } catch (Exception ex) {}

    }
```

...

```
@Entity
public class Software extends Model {

    @Column(unique = true)
    public String title;
```

But the test fails every time, because there is no any exception occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out:

I had a mistake, while building the Software instance. So, it works and throws the exception.

```
@Test
public void saveWithTitleNotUnique() {  // not unique title

    SoftwareTemplateBuilder builder1 = new SoftwareTemplateBuilder();
    Software software1 = builder1.template1().withTitle("title1").create();

    SoftwareTemplateBuilder builder2 = new SoftwareTemplateBuilder();
    Software software2 = builder2.template1().withTitle("title1").create();

    software1.save();

    try {
        software2.save();
        fail("software.title is not unique");
    } catch (PersistenceException ex) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you haven't made an instance of Software to have an exception ! 
you have to do a: `Software software = new Software();`

Comment: I created it by builder. Inside the create() method there is an new Software(). So, this is not a point.